# What logic is behind t('flash.notice.order.creditcard.valid')?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
flash[:notice] = t('flash.notice.order.creditcard.valid')
```

I can sort of guess what this flash message probably outputs to the user but what is this 't' method and what kind of object is `flash.notice.order.creditcard.valid`? Is this application-specific logic or a Rails usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

t is an alias for the [translate method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).  The `flash.notice.order.creditcard.valid` is the name of the message to translate.  It should be defined in the various locale files found in `config/locale/`.